# Correlation between Reputation score and Profile views

Tags: discussion, profile-page, users, statistics, personal-statistics

It would be interesting if there were was some kind of distinguishable correlation between a user's reputation and their profile views.

Is there a public list of all users and their stats out there?

I'm thinking along the lines of Facebook Graph, only, StackGraph!

Comment: To state the obvious, I'd say that it would be weakly correlated upward.

Comment: I think it's actually a fairly strong correlation, but I also think there's correlation at the "lots of points in a short amount of time" stat. My profile views went up quite a bit during the few weeks I was in the top 10 in a given week.

Comment: Take [Herb Sutter](http://stackoverflow.com/users/297582/herb-sutter) and [Herb Sutter](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1661064/herb-sutter). It doesn't correlate very well.

Comment: INteresting..How did you find that? I'd love to see a huge scatterplot of all users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the reasons why people look at your profile:

1. Hm, this person has a great answer, lets have a look at the profile to see there is more. Maybe I can learn something and spend a few upvotes.
2. Hm, this person has a terrible question or answer, lets have a look at the profile to see if there is more. Maybe I can see if this is a one off, or maybe I can close some questions or even spend some downvotes.
3. Hm, this person is either a spammer, or leaves rude comments, or has some other unacceptable behaviour. Lets check the profile, if there is more.
4. Hm, this person has a lot more badges and or reputation than me, lets have a look at the profile, to either learn from it, or feed my inner envy.
5. Hm, this person looks knowledgable, lets check the profile if there is some contact info.
6. Hm, this person has a nice profile picture, lets check the profile for some contact info or maybe a blog to learn more about the person.
7. Hm there is a meta post about this user, lets click on the link to see what is going on.

People with high reputation are within 3 (possibly 4) categories so in that case they are more likely to attracht more profile views. But more importantly, high reputation is often an older account, so there is more time to collect the views. So it would be interesting to compare accounts with similar age, but different reputation.

Answer (score 1):

There is, [sort of](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/95957#graph). Granted, taking the average is not the best way to go there, but being lazy and doing so does hint that being a well-known face (i.e. Jon Skeet) probably helps far more.

But to answer more generally, you can use [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to try and dig into the numbers to your satisfaction if you want.

Comment: You could probably cap that chart at 200k, since we only have ~25 users above that. They probably aren't the best statistical sample, and right now they're taking up more than half of that chart.

Comment: Yeah, I added some [additional restrictions](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/95960#graph) and it looks a bit more sane. Well, at least until you [decrease the rounding factor](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/95960#graph). Reminds me that graphing on Data Explorer needs some enhancements...

Comment: Maybe [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/r0b8e.png) – Pearson/Spearman correlation are 0.52, 0.53 respectively.

Comment: @slhck Ah, much nicer :)